Scene is lit but there isn't any light source

Hello! I taught myself Blender 2 weeks ago, i wanted to make a specific animation of a Piercing spinning around for a website im making. I did everything as good as i could and even rendered the animation in .pngs and made it into a .gif already, butin the every rendered Version it looks totally different than in Blender (not preview). No matter what i did the Lighting ALWAYS looks shit? I dont get it and i dont have the energy anymore to try fixing this. In the screenshot below i had NO LIGHTING at all (not world/scene Lights aswell) and STILL its overexposed in the render preview...
If anybody needs the .blend i can upload it.
thanks for reading

Blender has a built-in feature for screenshots Window > Save Screenshot. Uploading your file with https://blend-exchange.com/ would be great. There is light in your scene, judging by your screenshots. Probably coming from the world, which definitively has a material, otherwise it would be black.

It looks like in the viewport you're seeing Material Preview with a preset world lighting, but the full render is using Cycles with a white background color.  There are several questions on this site about using preview lighting in your render, that'd probably get you really close to what you expect.

It might be that you have Exposure and Gamma value wrong on Color Managment. 
If you want to have similar render result to Viewport you should use HDRI. You can quickly google to see how you can use HDRI in World.
Blender uses forest.exr as it's default hdri on material view. You can find the file here,
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\datafiles\studiolights\world
For more hdri images you can explore HDRI haven website.
https://hdri-haven.com/category/studio
